# Ability to select one item on each panel without it removing the selction on sibiling panels

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react app where i have a `CompaniesDashboard` that has three children `CompanyPanel`

I have a state called `data` that lives in the `CompaniesDashboard` that is an array of three objects, and each object has an array of `timeslots`

When i click on any of the `timeslots` it gets red, and if any of the other two `CompanyPanel` also have the same `timeslot` they get greyed out.

So lets say i click on the first timeslot on the first `CompanyPanel`, it gets red, and the same timeslots on the other `CompanyPanel` get greyed out.

And if i click on the second timeslot on the second `CompanyPanel`, it correclty gets red and the matching timeslots on the other CompanyPanels get correctly greyed out.

But the previous selected timeslot, the first timeslot on the first `CompanyPanel` gets reseted, set back to black its default color.

I want it so that, each `CompanyPanel` can have one selected `timeslot` as long as it is not the same `timeslot`, for example I can have one selected at 12:00 on the first `CompanyPanel`, and another one at 13:00 on the second `CompanyPanel`. But not both at 12:00.

This is the CompaniesDashboard where the state lives:

I also have a codesand where you can see it live: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-hypatia-ew1vh?fontsize=14

```
export default class CompaniesDashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      data,
      selectedTime: 'None',
      selectedCompany: 'None'
    }
    this.chooseTime = this.chooseTime.bind(this)
  }

  chooseTime (selectedTime, name) {
    this.setState({
      selectedTime: selectedTime.dateUTCString,
      selectedCompany: name
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { data, error, selectedTime, selectedCompany } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.isLoading() && <p>LOADING</p>}
        {error && <p>{error}</p>}

        <div className="flex">
          {data && data.map(({times, name, _id}, i) => (
            <CompanyPanel
              chooseTime={this.chooseTime}
              deleteTime={this.deleteTime}
              selectedTime={selectedTime}
              selectedCompany={selectedCompany}
              key={i}
              times={times}
              name={name}
              id={_id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is the CompanyPanel:

```
export default (props) => {
  const { selectedTime, times, chooseTime, deleteTime, name, selectedCompany } = props

  const colorClass = (time) => {
    let color = null;

    if (time.dateUTCString === selectedTime) {
      color = 'gray'
      if (name === selectedCompany) {
        color = 'red'
      }
    } 
    return color;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="flex-auto pa3">
        <div className="ba mv2">
          <p className="tc pa2 dib bg-near-white">{props.name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="ba mv2">
          <p className="tc pa2 dib bg-red white">{selectedTime}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="ba mv2 bg-light-gray">
          {times.map((time, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="bg-almost-white">
              <span className='pa2 red pointer ma2 bg-white' onClick={() => deleteTime(time, name)}>X</span>
              <p
                onClick={() => chooseTime(time, name)}
                className={`tc pa2 dib pointer ${colorClass(time, selectedCompany)}`}>
                {time.dateUTCString}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code and as per my understanding once you select the time under any company you're directly applying the color class based on the time and the company name that will not help you to preserve the time slot under the other company at the same time.

To achieve this I think you should have some value to preserve the old state in your state object.

```
this.state = {
  data,
  selectedTime: 'None',
  selectedCompany: 'None',
  prevData:{}
}
// Your chooseTime function will be something like this
chooseTime (selectedTime, name) {
this.setState({
  prevState: ...this.state,
  selectedTime: selectedTime.dateUTCString,
  selectedCompany: name
 })
}
```

And now before rendering the company panel component inside your colorClass() function before applying grey and red color class you can check inside your state object that you're mapping with the prevState object that which time inside which company panel you need to keep as red and which as grey. It will help you to display multiple time slots reserved under the different company panel.

Hope this helps. I just gave the idea sorry didn't provide the complete code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your state configuration is the problem. You have 3 companies, but you hold a state with only one `selectedTime` and one `selectedCompany`, so when you select a time and company- all 3 invoke their colorClass function (because selectedTime and selectedCompany props changes which causes a re-render), all colors reset to 'null' (which defaults to black) and then only the new selectedTime and selectedCompany remains.

There are couple of ways to solve this, my approach would be probably to keep 2 arrays- one for times, and one for selected companies. Time array might be const, as you said there are specific time frames you wish to be able to mark, and for each time slot you have the matching index in the other array to fill the company who picked it.

Then you pass that array to each company panel, and in colorClass it will iterate through the companies array. if the cell contains the company's name- it will mark the corresponding timeslot in red, if its another companies name- grey, and if its empty- black.

Also do not forget to empty the currently occupied cell if a company chooses another timeslot.

Comment: thanks @Gibor, but what so you mean by "Time array might be const" you mean I should fill the aray in in advance with all timeslots?
And I dont quite get what you  mean by  "for each time slot you have the matching index in the other array" could you please explain a bit more? thanks so much!

Comment: yeah sure: for the first question- yes, if this is going along with how your program works. obviously if you get the times from external source or generating them yourself and they could change it won't be const. if they're the same no matter what- better build a const times array so it is known they should not be changed.

Comment: and for the 2nd question- I mean you create the companies array in the same length of the times array, so companies[0] will hold the name of the company occupying the time-slot in times[0], companies[1] will hold the company name occupying the timeslot in times[1], and so on. You will have direct correlation between the two so it will be really easy to know exactly which company occupy which timeslot.

Comment: You can also of course do it with one array of objects with "time" and "company" properties, but iterating on arrays is easier and more intuitive imo, because of array operations.

Comment: ahh so you mean, lets say timeslots array has length of 10, then I would create a companies array of the same length, 10, and initially fill it with nulls, then if i click on a the first slot,  I would fill the first slot of the companies array with the company name i clicked on, is that what you mean?

Comment: exaclty. and you would pass that array as props to your company panel component, which will iterate over it and apint it like this:
1. timeslots which have null (or empty string) in the corresponding company array slot- black color
2. timslots with same company name as the panel represnts - red
3. timeslots with different company name- grey

and every time this array changes it will re-render all your company panels to re-draw with the appropriate color